# COBOL substring between two finite points

Tags: string, substring, cobol, gnucobol

I understand that the `string_variable(start:length)` can be used to get a substring of a string given a starting point and substring length, however, I am finding that I often need to get a substring between a 'start' and 'end' point.

While I know I could always do this:

```
SUBTRACT start FROM end GIVING len
string(start:len)
```

It seems cumbersome to have to do so every time when I am writing programs that use this functionality often. Is there perhaps a quicker/built-in way of achieving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about?

```
    move str (start-pos : end-pos - start-pos + 1) to ...
```

You can subtract the first from the last, but you need to add 1 to get the correct length.

`STRING` is a statement name, as is `START`, and `END` is reserved. `LENGTH` is a function name. I avoid those in anything that looks like code.

Comment: Just to add for @matt-haidet: You can also simply drop the `len` if you want the complete rest of the field.
If you use a current compiler (which I assume as you've added the gnucobol tag ;-) then you can also create a user-defined function which takes those three parameters (maybe the len as optional) and returns the result back...